# Datatable child row problem with searching box SQLSTATE[42S22] ERROR

Tags: javascript, database, laravel, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have a problem with the data table child row. When searching with the search box I throw the following error.
The main problem is when I want to perform the search.
I am sending the data through the server-side function, as the table is almost 5 million records

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjZTv.jpg)

The data was sent by ajax in a json file.
I am working with Laravel

This is the datatable code.

```
<script>
function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>ID:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.id+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td><b>Dirección</b></td>'+
            '<td></td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Calle:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.calle+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Número:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.numero+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Interior:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.interior+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Código Postal:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.codigopostal+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '</table>';
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#laravel_datatable').DataTable( {

        "processing": false,
        "serverSide": true,
        "responsive": true,
        "cache": true,
        "ajax": "{{ url('ine.list')}}",

        "language": {url: 'http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Spanish.json'},
        "scrollY": 400,
        "length" : 5000,
        "deferRender":    true,
        "scroller":       true,
        "columns": [
            {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data": "nombre" },
            { "data": "apellidopaterno" },
            { "data": "apellidomaterno" },
            { "data": "fechanacimiento" },
            { "data": "actividad","bSortable": false }
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    } );

    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#laravel_datatable tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );

        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    } );
} );


  </script>

There is a small difference that makes the search box work once and throw the error on another.

This is when it works:
```

**Laravel Controller**

```
 $ine_puebla = DB::table('ine_puebla')->orderBy('id')->get();


 return datatables()->of($ine_puebla)->make(true);
```

JSON File

```
"draw": 0,
  "recordsTotal": 500,
  "recordsFiltered": 500,
  "data": [

...

{
      "id": "500",
      "apellidopaterno": "TORRES",
      "apellidomaterno": "ROJAS",
      "nombre": "MAYRA",
      "fechanacimiento": "19820725",
      "actividad": "AMA DE CASA",
      "calle": "C 4 PONIENTE",
      "numero": "506",
      "interior": null,
      "colonia": "BARR SAN ANTONIO",
      "codigopostal": "75120"
    }
  ],
  "input": [

  ]
}
```

**Now when you throw the error**

```
Now the difference when it does not work at the end of the JSON file is added a query that is the one that conflicts with the search box:
```

Laravel Controller

```
$ine_puebla = DB::table('ine_puebla');


     return datatables()->of($ine_puebla)->make(true);
```

**JSON File**

```
 "draw": 0,
      "recordsTotal": 500,
      "recordsFiltered": 500,
      "data": [

    ...

    {
          "id": "500",
          "apellidopaterno": "TORRES",
          "apellidomaterno": "ROJAS",
          "nombre": "MAYRA",
          "fechanacimiento": "19820725",
          "actividad": "AMA DE CASA",
          "calle": "C 4 PONIENTE",
          "numero": "506",
          "interior": null,
          "colonia": "BARR SAN ANTONIO",
          "codigopostal": "75120"
        }
      ]

  "queries": [
    {
      "query": "select count(*) as aggregate from (select '1' as `row_count` from `ine_puebla`) count_row_table",
      "bindings": [

      ],
      "time": "0.95"
    },
    {
      "query": "select * from `ine_puebla`",
      "bindings": [

      ],
      "time": "3.96"
    }
  ],
  "input": [

  ]
}
```

Comment: Does your table have a `ine_puebla` column?

Comment: It looks like a problem on the laravel side.
When you do ajax call on datatable, you need to prepare the data expected by datatable and also, have a closer look at the query parameters sent by datatable while call the URL('ine.list') for data. 

-1st get the searched text from query parameter and the do query on laravel side and return exactly datatable expect.

Comment: `ine_puebla` is the name of the table

Comment: I send a json file by ajax. Laravel is sent in this way  `return datatables () -> eloquent (BuscatuIne :: query ()) -> toJson ();`

Comment: The documentation to do it through the server-side is using this package:[link] (https://packagist.org/packages/yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle)

Comment: I think I found what is happening, I don't know how to solve it.